# How do you stop Jest from logging exceptions when testing a React component using expect().toThrow()?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a React component which I'm testing:

```
function Component(props) {
    if (!Number.isInteger(props.integer)) {
        throw new Error('Not an integer!');
    }

    return <p>{props.integer}</p>
}
```

Using this test in jest:

```
expect(() =>
    render(
        <Component integer={1.5} />
    )
).toThrow();
```

However when running `jest` the exception is logged to the console but the test passes.

I would like the test to pass and for the exception to not be logged so that it doesn't pollute the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `render` function to stop throwing exception in console, you just need to mock `console`, using `jest.spyOn` inside your test.

```js
test('should throw an error when the integer prop is not an integer', () => {
  const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation(() => {});
  
  expect(() =>
    render(<Component integer={1.5} />)
  ).toThrow();
  
  consoleSpy.mockRestore();
});
```